# Cant use Routes from express

Tags: node.js, typescript, mean-stack

When I use

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/users', (req, res) => res.json({'name':'luka'}));
```

and i go to localhost:4000/users/ i get a valid response.

But when I change it to using routers:

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const router = express.Router();
router.use('/users', userRouter);

app.get('/', router);
```

where userRouter is imported and looks like this:

```
import express from 'express';
const userRouter = express.Router();
userRouter.route('/').get(
    (req, res)=>{
        res.json({'name':'luka'});
    }
);
export default userRouter;
```

I get 'CANNOT GET /users/' message. I don't know what can be a problem, any suggestions?

Comment: can you change `app.get('/', router)` to `app.use('/', router)`

Comment: i will kill myself :) solved it, you are a king